# How to add text between two radio buttons of same group

Tags: html, web, visual-web-developer

I am trying to create a selection in which I have two radio buttons of same group and some text in between.  Like single correct MCQ...

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio"> This_1 <br> 
    or <br>
    <input type="radio"> This_2
</body>
</html>
```

Now what I want is that user can select only one of the radio button.
However, as soon as I add **OR** in between, the radio buttons divide into two groups. And instead I can select both of them,u know what I'm saying...
Please help is really appreciated.
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?:

```html
<p>Select an option:</p>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="1" name="options" value="1"
         checked>
  <label for="huey">1</label>
</div>

<p>TEXT 1</p>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="2" name="options" value="2">
  <label for="dewey">2</label>
</div>

<p>TEXT 2</p>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="3" name="options" value="3">
  <label for="louie">3</label>
</div>
```